# Why does AudioFlinger fail without programmatic indication?

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm having a problem where SoundPool crashes, but gives no programmatic indication that is has crashed.  After it crashes, it will not play any more sounds until the application is reloaded (exiting via back button then restarting is not sufficient).  LogCat gives me these error messages:

```
AudioFlinger: no more track names availlable [sic]
AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
```

Yet, despite these errors, SoundPool.play() still returns a positive integer that increments for each new play request which, according to the documentation, indicates that there was not an error.  Someone else started an Issue for this problem:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13453

...however, there have been no responses.  The code below is a minimalist Activity to consistently recreate this issue.  Just create a new Android project, set the ID of the LinearLayout to main_bg, set the ID of the TextView to main_tv, and add a sound file named ding to res/raw.  The sound file needs to be long enough to click on the screen four times before the first sound completes; mine is a 1.7-second 22050 Hz mono MP3 @ 96kbps.  After a brief pause, the fifth click will generate the error messages above via LogCat.  Or, you can just click a bunch of times until sounds stop playing.

I have tested the error messages to occur on a T-Mobile G1 running Android 1.6, but they do not occur on a 1.6 emulator, a 2.1 emulator, or a 2.2 emulator.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or is SoundPool just worthless for coincident sound effects on a G1?

Code:

```
public class SoundTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
   private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
   private  int index = 0;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      findViewById(R.id.main_bg).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

      initSounds();
      mSoundPoolMap.put(index, mSoundPool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ding, 1));
   }

   public void initSounds() { 
      mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
      mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();           
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      int result = mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), 0.99f, 0.99f, 1, 0, 1f);
      ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_tv)).setText(Integer.toString(result));
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I don't like the look of this...

```
findViewById(R.id.main_bg).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
```

When you do this, the view is found and inflated allowing you to use `setOnClickListener()` but it is not being assigned to anything. I'm guessing at some point it is being garbage collected which may be causing your problem.

Your description says it's a LinearLayout? If so, try this...

```
public class SoundTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private int index = 0;
    private LinearLayout ll = null; // ADD THIS!!!

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ll = findViewById(R.id.main_bg); // ASSIGN TO ll
        ll.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this); // SET LISTENER
```

Comment: How would a UI problem affect AudioFlinger?  And main_bg isn't going to be garbage collected; it's still referenced by the rest of the user interface.  The line you highlight is just fine.